# Remove weather of default location in zWeatherFeed jquery plugin ?

Tags: jquery, api, yahoo-api, yahoo-weather-api

How do i remove the default location Las Palmas. I searched for the parameters that invokes the weatherfeed for Las Palmas in js file but couldn't find it.
When i pass the id of my city as parameter weather of both city is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must edit the yahoo city code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').weatherfeed(['XXXX0977'], {
        forecast: true
    });
});
</script>
```

the XXXX0977 is the city code you need to change.

Comment: Thaks Sarah for your help.